# How can I set a specific positon in a String in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a String with name str.

```
str = "hi john";
```

Now I want to set `j` char to `g`. How can I do that?

Comment: If you made your question less ambiguous you'd probably get better help.

Comment: There seems to be only 1 character of 'j' and 'g'. Why are you then talking about replacing all ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modify a `String` directly, but you can either use a StringBuilder:

```
str = "hi john";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.setCharAt(3,'g');
str = sb.toString();
```

.. or convert it to a `char[]` and back

```
str = "hi john";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
chars[3] = 'g';
str = new String(chars);
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways :

a. This will replace all occurances of '`j`' with '`g`'.

```
String str1 = "hi john";    
System.out.println(str1);  // prints - hi john  

String str2 = str1.replace('j', 'g');  
System.out.println(str2);  // prints - hi gohn
```

b. If you wish to change the '`j`' character only at **one location** in the string, you may want to do like this.

```
String str4 = replaceCharAt("hi john", 3,'g');  

public static String replaceCharAt(String str1, int pos, char c) {
  StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(str1);
  buf.setCharAt(pos,c);
  return buf.toString( );
}  

// Here : pos = 3, char = 'g' and str1 = "hi john"
```

Comment: Any special reason to suggest `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @Andreas_D : No special reason .. Just used it. You can also use StringBuilder.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Both StringBuffer and StringBuilder have same API so you can use any one and only Difference is StringBuilder is not Thread safe.So the methods of StringBuilder class are not synchronized.

Comment: @Uttam - trust me, I know the difference very well and there is absolutely no need to use `StringBuffer` in Java 1.5+. You'll find al lot of interesting Q/A here on SO, especially on the legendary *thread-safeness* of `StringBuffer` ;) Just wanted to know, if I've missed something.

Comment: @Andreas_D: yes sir you are right because StringBuilder is faster than StringBuffer. StringBuilder is added in java 5 apart from synchronization its good to use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

`str = str.replace('j', 'g');` should do it for you.

Comment: it replace all of j with g!!i need to replace on of them with g.

Comment: in that case you would know the index of the 'j'! Right?

Comment: @mehdi - you didn't tell us that only *1* character shall be replaced. If this now is the case: Which character do you want to replace, the first one, the last one, the nth? What's the rule?

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replace('j','g');
```

as this java api shows
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)

Comment: Note that `str` remains unchanged. `str.replace('j','g');` returns a new string with j's replaced by g's

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
String str ="hi john"
syso(str.replace('j','g'));
```

Output will be **hi gohn**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring. Look at :http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
public static String replace(String _text, String _searchStr, String _replacementStr) {
    // String buffer to store str
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    // Search for search
    int searchStringPos = _text.indexOf(_searchStr);
    int startPos = 0;
    int searchStringLength = _searchStr.length();

    // Iterate to add string
    while (searchStringPos != -1) {
    sb.append(_text.substring(startPos, searchStringPos)).append(_replacementStr);
    startPos = searchStringPos + searchStringLength;
    searchStringPos = _text.indexOf(_searchStr, startPos);
    }

    // Create string
    sb.append(_text.substring(startPos,_text.length()));

    return sb.toString();
    }

public static int indexOf(String sb, String str, int start){
    int index = -1;
    if((start>=sb.length() || start<-1) || str.length()<=0) return index;
    char[] tofind = str.toCharArray();
    outer: for(;start<sb.length(); start++){
        char c = sb.charAt(start);
        if(c==tofind[0]){
            if(1==tofind.length) return start;
            inner: for(int i = 1; i<tofind.length;i++){ // start on the 2nd character
                char find = tofind[i];
                int currentSourceIndex = start+i;
                if(currentSourceIndex<sb.length()){
                    char source = sb.charAt(start+i);
                    if(find==source){
                        if(i==tofind.length-1){
                            return start;
                        }
                        continue inner;
                    } else {
                        start++;
                        continue outer;
                    }
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s;
int i = str.indexOf('j');
s = str.subString(0, i) + 'g' + str.subString(i + 1, str.length() - 1);
```